# Does $\sigma$ -compact imply separable?

Tags: metric-spaces, compactness

Let $D$ be a metric space. If $D$ is $\sigma$-compact, does this imply that $D$ is separable? I thought I had a proof, but I think it is wrong.
my proof:

Let $K_n$ the compact sets such that $K_n \nearrow D$. Then $K_n$ are sub metric spaces of $D$ so all the $K_n$ are separable.
Let $\{ (x_p^n): p \in \mathbb{N} \}$ the countable dense set of $K_n$. I think now $\{ (x_p^n): p,n \in \mathbb{N} \}$ is a countable dense set of $D$. The fac, it is countable is clear. If $G$ is an open set, then there exists a $K_n$ such that $G \subset K_n$ and because every $K_n$ separable, there exist a $p \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $x_n^p \in D$. So $D$ is seperable.

The problem is that i can't prove the statement: $G$ open then there exists a $K_n$ such that $G \subset K_n$. Can someone prove this , or is this statement false ?

Comment: Why do you need to prove that statement?  To show your set $\{ (x_{p}^{n} : p, \, n \in \Bbb N \}$ is dense, you just need to show its closure equals $D$.  But this set is the union of dense sets.  Is it true that the closure of an arbitrary union equals the union of the closures?  If so, then the closure of that sequence equals the union of closures where you view that set as the union of dense subsets of $K_{n}$.  Then the closure of each subset is actually $K_{n}$, so the union of the closures would be the union of $K_{n}$'s, which would equal $D$.

Comment: So in my opinion, you should try to prove (assuming it's true) that $\overline{\bigcup \limits_{\alpha} A_{\alpha}} = \bigcup \limits_{\alpha} \overline{A_{\alpha}}$.

Comment: Your statement that the closure of an arbitrary union equals the union of the closures, does not hold. Check: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/195311/union-of-closure-of-sets-is-the-closure-of-the-union

Comment: Ok, my approach was wrong, but I don't understand where you are going with your approach.  What's your reasoning for trying to find an open set $G$?

Comment: a set $\{ x_n | n \in \mathbb{N} \}$ is dense in $D$ if for every open set in $D$ there is a $x_n$ such that $x_n \in G$ . So I want to prove that for an arbitrary open set $G$, there is an $x_n$ such that $x_n \in G$ .

Comment: Oh yeah! A set is dense if it intersects with every open set. Ok, let me think about this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The statement is of course not true. Take $G$ to be the entire space, for example.

But what you *can* prove is that there is some $n$ such that $G\cap K_n$ is not empty, and therefore relatively open there. And then it meets the relevant dense set. (Of course, assuming $G\neq\varnothing$, which is of course the initial assumption.)

Comment: So ,  if $G$ is open in $D$ then there exists an $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $G \cap K_n$ is not empty and so $G \cap K_n$ is open in $K_n$,  so there exists a $x_p^n \in G \cap K_n \subset G$ ?

Comment: Yes, that is the idea. Now show that there is such $n$.

Comment: a proof by contradiction: If there is no $n$ such that $K_n \cap G = \emptyset$ and $K_n \nearrow D$, then  $\bigcup K_n \cap G = \emptyset$. This is a contradiction because $G \subset D$.  ?

Comment: Yes. And why does $G\cap K_n$ must be open in $K_n$?

Comment: $K_n$ is a subspace of $D$, so  the topology on K_n is $T_{K_n} =  \{ B \subset K_n : \exists A \mbox{ open }: B = A \cap K_n \}$ and this is metrizable too .

Comment: Just the fact it is metrizable is not enough. It might be a different metric and a different topology. The important thing is that the $K_n$ in the original topology is exactly the induced subspace here.

Comment: can you explain it a bit further? Because i don't know exactly what you mean by : ' The important thing is that the Kn in the original topology is exactly the induced subspace here" . (Btw: thank you for all your efforts you do on this topic. :-) )

Comment: The induced topology is exactly $T_{K_n}$ as you wrote it in your previous comment. And I'm just belabouring the point. I thought that you were given an increasing sequence of compact spaces and a metric on its union. But now I see it's the other way around. So yeah, there's no need to go further.