# Path component of finite set containing closures of all its points is closed

Tags: general-topology

Today I saw the following question on my exam.

> Let $X$ be a topological space consisting of finitely many points and suppose $x_0,x_1\in X$ are such that $x_1\in\overline{\{x_0\}}$. Prove that $$\gamma:[0,1]\to X:t\mapsto\begin{cases}x_0\quad\text{if }\ t<1\\x_1\quad\text{if }\ t=1\end{cases}$$ is a continuous map and prove that the path components of $X$ are closed.

The first part was easy for me. Suppose $U\subset X$ is open. There are four cases:

- $x_0,x_1\in U$, then $\gamma^{-1}(U)=[0,1]$ is open in $[0,1]$
- $x_0,x_1\not\in U$, then $\gamma^{-1}(U)=\emptyset$ is open in $[0,1]$
- $x_0\in U$, $x_1\not\in U$,  then $\gamma^{-1}(U)=[0,1)$ is open in $[0,1]$
- $x_0\not\in U$, $x_1\in U$. This is not possible. For then $X-U$ is closed, thus $\overline{\{x_0\}}\subset X-U\not\ni x_1$

Thus $\gamma$ is continuous. So if $P$ is a path component and $p\in P$, $\overline{\{p\}}\subset P$, but I don't see how this leads to $\overline{P}=P$. As far as I can see, we cannot just say that $$\overline{P}=\bigcup_{p\in P}\overline{\{p\}},$$ for example it does not work for $(0,1)\subset\mathbb{R}$, though it might hold because $X$ is finite; I only don't see how. Surely, I have to use finiteness of $X$ and judging on the amount of points the question was worth, I bet it is simple. Still I thought about it a long time and I don't see it. I'm curious about the solution. Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Closure distributes over finite unions, basically because finite unions of closed sets are closed.

Comment: @jgon I didn't know this. Actually my question then comes down to the following, thus can be considered as answered. Thanks you for your 
comment! https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/195311/union-of-closure-of-sets-is-the-closure-of-the-union-true-for-finite-false-for

Comment: Glad it was helpful :)